# Laravel app.js block all other scripts

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have a simple app with Laravel and each time I want to import a script the script doesn't work until I remove the app.js, but Laravel need this app.js.

For example now I try to implement the jQuery plugin "Chosen" when I remove the app.js, the plugin work fine, when I import app.js the plugin is broken.

What can I do?

Comment: what's the laravel version?

Comment: The last one, 5.6

Comment: so you are building with js with webpack right ? (laravel mix)

Comment: No, i just import my files, I don't have npm to install laravel mix, but that's the same than includes all files no ? Mix just put together all files in one bigger

Comment: then you can remove all the code in app.js, laravel doesn't need this file unless you using laravel mix

Comment: When I remove app.js some things stop working (things made with jQuery), but I include the last version of jQuery, why it's still not workign ? For example the dropdown menu of the current user

Comment: app.js mean js inside the resource folder right ?

Comment: No it's the public/js/app.js

Comment: ahh thought this: `resources/assets/js/app.js`

Comment: ok after remove it what's the error you getting ?

Comment: I don't get any error, just the other script stop working if I add app.js (for example the jquery chosen plugin), and there is nothing in the console. If I remove app.js no error too, the plugins works but not the dropdown menu and some other feature in jquery like bootstrap panels

Comment: you don't even get 404 error after your delete the file ?

Comment: No, I remove the include of app.js, I found one error : $(...).modal is not a function, this is strange because in my page there is jQuery imported

Comment: have you included jquery and bootstrap with cdn ?

Comment: boottstrap with cdn and jQuery with google ajax

Comment: what's the bootstrap version ?

Comment: you need bootstrap 4 and jquery 3.2

Comment: I have bootstrap 3.3.7 (that's the latest link from bootstrap) and jquery 3.3.1

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#css

Comment: I still have this : $(...).modal is not a function and this $.ajaxSetup, all functions of jquery seems don't work and the thing VERY strange, is that the modal works on one page but throw an error on another one

Comment: can i see the  how you included js files ?